# Change tintColor of custom navigation bar image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar with an UIImage. I want to change the colour of it, but when I use my code, the default black colour is used. My code is below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 26, height: 26))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "pinpoint.png")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pinpoint.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 86.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

The colour I want to use is on the last line of the snippet.

Comment: To use the tint color you need to use always template rendering mode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"pinpoint.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 86.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Hope this help. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Lamit :)

Comment: What did that solve? Nothing changed in the last line. The only thing the answerer did was to change the name of the file loaded, remove two redundant lines of code since you set your image property twice, and remove your frame sizing.

Comment: exactly, only important thing is rendering mode, if use original rendering, you can change tint color of image. I change it to AlwaysTemplate, and edit code to readably understand.